# How to create a Latex timeline with images for certain time points

Tags: timeline

I would like to create a timeline by using latex, however different than the examples over the [internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217834/how-to-create-a-timeline-with-latex), I want my timeline to have images representing the certain times. You can check my perfectly drawn timeline on paint.

[image]

I tried to achieve this however, images were too small, and could not be able put the above the timeline:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=3.5cm,nodes={text width=3cm,align=left}]
    \draw[black,->,thick,>=latex,line cap=rect]
      (0,0) -- (3.5,0);
    \foreach \Xc in {0,...,3}
    {
      \draw[black,thick] 
        (\Xc,0) -- ++(0,5pt);
    }
    
    \node[below,align=left,anchor=north,inner xsep=0pt,color=black] 
      at (0,0) 
      {Hint is given};  
    
    \node[below,align=left,anchor=north,inner xsep=0pt] 
      at (1,0) 
      {Robot directs correct hole with Gaze Cue};  
    
    \node[below,align=left,anchor=north,inner xsep=0pt] 
      at (2,0) 
      {Partipicant drives the screw to the correct Hole};
    
    \node[below,align=left,anchor=north,inner xsep=0pt] 
      at (3,0) 
      {\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{figures/ExperimentArchitecture.png}  Robot nods its head};


\end{tikzpicture}
```

Which looks like below:

[image]

Comment: Well if you go by the TikZ solutions, you can have `\includegraphics` inside nodes and you’re done. ;)

Comment: @Archange Can you post an answer plz? It should be really easy, and since there is no question similar to this one it would be helpful to others and me (At least I couldn't see any image)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us your tex code you have tried so far ...

Comment: @Mensch First I though archange's answer was enough but it wasnt. He only showed me how to put image. But I need to orginize them. Image is on top or on down along with the text. How can I do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    x=3.5cm,
    nodes={text width=3cm},
    image/.style={
        above,
        anchor=south,
        inner xsep=0pt,
    },
    legend/.style={
        below,
        align=left,
        anchor=north,
        inner xsep=0pt,
    },
]
    \draw[black,->,thick,>=latex,line cap=rect]
        (0,0) -- (3.5,0);
    \foreach \Xc in {0,...,3}
    {
        \draw[black,thick] 
            (\Xc,0) -- ++(0,5pt);
    }
    \draw (0,0) node[image] {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}};
    \draw (0,0) node[legend] {Hint is given};

    \draw (1,0) node[image] {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}};
    \draw (1,0) node[legend] {Robot directs correct hole with Gaze Cue}; 

    \draw (2,0) node[image] {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}};
    \draw (2,0) node[legend] {Partipicant drives the screw to the correct Hole};

    \draw (3,0) node[image] {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}};
    \draw (3,0) node[legend] {Robot nods its head};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Before you posted an answer I could be able to achieve, but yours look more organised. I liked it more.

Comment: Indeed, if you use them often defining node styles is a good idea. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this for instance (based on your example):

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=3.5cm,nodes={text width=3cm,align=left}]
    \draw[black,->,thick,>=latex,line cap=rect]
      (0,0) -- (3.5,0);
    \foreach \Xc in {0,...,3}
    {
      \draw[black,thick] 
        (\Xc,0) -- ++(0,5pt);
    }
    
    \node[below,align=left,anchor=north,inner xsep=0pt,color=black] 
      at (0,0) 
      {Hint is given};  
    
    \node[below,align=left,anchor=north,inner xsep=0pt] 
      at (1,0) 
      {Robot directs correct hole with Gaze Cue};  
    
    \node[below,align=left,anchor=north,inner xsep=0pt] 
      at (2,0) 
      {Partipicant drives the screw to the correct Hole};
    
    \node[below,align=left,anchor=north,inner xsep=0pt] 
      at (3,0) 
      {  Robot nods its head};

    \node[above] at (3,0) {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:
[image: timelinewithpictureabove]

But if you did not get to that from your example, I suggest learning TikZ basics to go further (node placement especially). ;)